# Trying to read all response headers through angular interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to read response header through an $httpProvider interceptor to read all headers of all ajax request.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q',function($q) {
    'response': function(response) {
            console.log("=====");
            console.log(response);
            console.log("=====");
     }
}]);
```

in this way i can see on chrome debugger i can see:

[image]

i'd like to access to header fields reading "b" property that contains a 'stringify' rappresentation of header response (screenshot below show chrome debugger in Network >> XHR for the same response header)

[image]

How can i do to read "b" property? Maybe there is a another way to do that?

Comment: You'd have to access the headers by name: `response.headers('Pragma')` and `response.headers('X-Ekbl-Debug-SQL')`

Comment: great!!! it was so easy. Thank you so much.